# Disk created from GCP snapshot doesn't resize in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-pvc

I've created GCP's disk form a snapshot and now I'm trying to resize it using PVC in kubernetes: 100GB -> 400GB. I've applied:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: restored-resize
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
allowVolumeExpansion: true
reclaimPolicy: Retain
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: restored-graphite
spec:
  storageClassName: restored-resize
  capacity:
    storage: 400G
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: dev-restored-graphite
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: restored-graphite
spec:
  # It's necessary to specify "" as the storageClassName
  # so that the default storage class won't be used, see
  # https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1
  storageClassName: restored-resize
  volumeName: restored-graphite
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 400G
```

Status in PVC shows 400G:

```
(...)
status:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 400G
  phase: Bound
```

However pod mounts previous disk value:

```
/dev/sdc                 98.4G     72.8G     25.6G  74% /opt/graphite/storage
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you delete pods after changing pvc?

Comment: Yes. Scaled them to 0.

Answer (score 1):

To me seems that you have setted 400G directly on the manifest, but as the manual said, you should had edited only

```
resources:
    requests:
      storage: 400G
```

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/

and those, triggering the new condition: `FileSystemResizePending`

As of Kubernetes v1.11, those PVC will autoresize in time after some time in this status, due to that, you shouldn't even have to restart the pod bounded to the pc.

But, again on your problem: i would edit this way the manifes:

```
spec:
  storageClassName: restored-resize
  capacity:
    storage: 100G
```

in order for the system to reload the old config and notice that the situation is not as he thinks.
or at least, that is what i would try (on another environment, not production for sure.)